# Keeping the Children's props independent of each other - given they come from the same .map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am adding an element with the following onClick event in the array `addElement`
(the state is: `const [add,setAdd]=React.useState([])`):
(handlers in the parent component)

```
const handleClickAddgroup = (event) => {
        setAdd([...add,
            {id: getUid(), ...ourObject}
        ])
    }
```

This is how each item is being selected:

```
const handleProduct = (value,key) => {
        setProduct(key,value);
    };
```

In the parent component, I want to render for each element in the `addElement` array the
`ControlledOpenSelect` component:

```
{addElement.map(item=>{
            return <ControlledOpenSelect ourObject={ourObject} key={item.id} onRemove={handleRemoveAGroup} item={item} onChange={handleProduct} 
            handleClose={handleClose} handleOpen={handleOpen} handleQuantity={handleQuantity} handleRemoveAGroup={handleRemoveAGroup} price={price}
            subTotal={subTotal} product={product} open={open}/>
        })}
```

The `ControlledOpenSelect` itself looks like this:

```
const ControlledOpenSelect=({ourObject,item,handleOpen,handleClose,onChange,handleQuantity,handleRemoveAGroup,price,product,subTotal,open})=>{

    const handleProduct=(event)=>{
        onChange(item.id,event.target.value)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={handleOpen}>
                        Open the select
      </Button>
                    <FormControl >
                        <InputLabel id="demo-controlled-open-select-label">Product</InputLabel>
                        <Select **I think in this component is a problem**
                            labelId="demo-controlled-open-select-label"
                            id="demo-controlled-open-select"
                            open={open}
                            onClose={()=>handleClose()}
                            onOpen={()=>handleOpen()}
                            value={product}
                            onChange={handleProduct}
                            key={item.id}
                        >
                            {Object.entries(item).filter(([key]) => key !== 'id').map(
                                ([key, value]) => <MenuItem key={key} value={key}>{key}</MenuItem>
                            )}
                        </Select>
                        <div>
                            <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Quantity" variant="outlined" onChange={(event)=>handleQuantity(event)} key={item.id}/>
                            <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Price" variant="outlined" value={price} disabled key={item.id}/>
                            <p>{Number.isFinite(subTotal) ? subTotal : 0}</p>
                        </div>
                    </FormControl>
                    <button type="button" onClick={()=>handleRemoveAGroup(item.id)}>Delete</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

My problem is that every time I change something in one rendered child, it changes the props to every child displayed. I have to mention that I do know that in this particular case alone Its better to move state into `ControlledOpenSelect` but that is not really an option for me , as I want to keep the states in the parent because I will need them down the line. Thank you very much!
(P.S. any other component that was not mentioned is imported from Material UI)

Comment: You did not show the function that changes the props. In `ControlledOpenSelect` you used the `onChange` props which calls `handleProduct`. What happened there?

Comment: @Someone Special 1 Apologies ! This is in `ControlledOpenSelect ` : `const handleProduct=(event)=>{onChange(item.id,event.target.value)}`. And this is  `handleProduct`:  `  const handleProduct = (value,key) => {
        setProduct(key,value);
    };`

Comment: Add them to the corresponding code block in your question. The clearer your question is, the faster you get a response. You are rendering the ControlledOpenSelect from addElements but you are using `setProduct(key,value)` so we can't tell how you are associating them.

Comment: @ Someone Special Just did it ! Thank you very much !

Comment: As i stated in previous comment. you use setProduct but you are mapping with `addElement`, why aren't you modifying the addElement state?

Comment: @Someone Special addElement is an array with the number of elements equal to the number of times I want the ControlledOpenSelect to render

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your child(ren) component(s) using `memo` higher order :

```
export default React.memo(function myChild(props) {

})
```

And you need use `useCallBack` hook when passing main state change functions as prop to children. e.g

```
function ParentCMPNT() {
   const [x,setX] = React.useState();

   const handleXupdate = React.useCallBack((value)=>setX(value),[]); // add dependencies too.
   return (
       <MyChild onUpdate={handleXupdate}>
       <MyChild onUpdate={handleXupdate}>
       // ...

   )
}
```

Comment: also you need ```useMemo``` when passing specific variables to children. Please study about how to prevent wasted renders in React.

Comment: It doesnt work... I have updated the handleProduct like this ; `const handleProduct = React.useCallback((value,key) => {
        setProduct(key,value);
    },[]);` and I have also wrapped every instance of the child in useMemo, yet I encounter the same problem: when one Element changes in a child , it reflects in the same chage in all other children

Comment: @PeterMalik give me a ```stackblitz``` or other online ```ide``` link which there's completed code.

Comment: Sure , it's here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ggkgsx?file=src/index.js. Thank you very much ! For some reason , it works in VSCode yet here it says there's some problem with the hooks, but on CodeSandbox works :https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-fire-qtcmi?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @PeterMalik there's too many errors there. See this example for preventing wasted rednders: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qiicoy, you need to open console.

Comment: I have figured out my mistake: the keys passed into each child.  Thank you very much !